How to install latest Python patch on older versions?
I've had a look online and can't figure out how to install the latest patch on an older version of Python.
I'm on Windows, with no admin rights. I want to upgrade 3.10.1 to 3.10.15, without losing any of my installed libraries (like pandas). I don't want to upgrade to the latest minor version (3.12.x).
Common answers:

just download the latest installer?! No, I need to use 3.10.x for various reasons. 3.10.15 doesn't have an .exe installer to download


use chocolatey. No, I can't as I don't have admin rights on my work laptop


extract the tarball. I've downloaded Python-3.10.15.tgz and can extract using tar command, but where do I extract it to? The extracted root folder is called 'Python-3.10.15' whereas my current Python folder is called 'Python310', so I'm not sure an extraction would overwrite...

Any ideas or reference docs?

"3.10.15 doesn't have an .exe installer to download" - For context, the release page only has source tarballs and says "According to the release calendar ... binary installers are no longer provided for [Python 3.10]" (along with more details).

The tarball is source code, so you'd need to compile it yourself.

Have you considered conda? They have 3.10.14 in Anaconda and Conda-Forge.

@wjandrea thanks. what does 'compile it yourself' practically mean? I assume it's not as simple as extracting the tarball into a folder...

I've never done it myself, but here's the guide
